# NBA traveling and what steps count towards it

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

In this video I’m confused on the steps that count towards a travel. It seems like the step counter is wrong in a lot of them. At 1 minute into the video, how many steps does Noah really take? It seems like a lot of steps that are the non pivot foot are counted when they shouldn’t be right? How many steps does Kyle Korver take at 1:30? At 2:45 is it more like 4 or 5 steps because only the steps of the pivot foot should count and not the non pivot foot?